# Java Generic Interface method-overload

Tags: java, generics, overloading

I'm trying to make a interface for my Task sheet at university. I have to implement all this methods for various data-structs so I would like to implement this interface.

The Problem is, the data-structs have to be generic ex: `LinearList<T>` where the type of key is T. Now different data-structs have different Elements ex. a `LinearList<T>` has `ListItem<T>` as elements and Trees have `TreeNode<T>`.

So I thought I make a interface with `<C, T>` where C = ListItem and T the type ex. Integer.

Now i have some overloaded methods ex:

```
insert(T key)
insert(ListItem<T> item)
```

so the user can add a key or he can add for example the head of another list. But now I'm getting a compiler error i dont understand:

```
java:15: error: name clash: insert(T,int) and insert(C,int) have the same erasure
    boolean insert(T key, int pos);
```

What can I do to enable overloading the way I explained above? Because in a abstract class I tried it and it worked.

**Edit:**
Okay like in the comments discussed I use different method names now. It seams to be the solution other collections use to solve the problem and as mentioned hides(?) more implementation details. Many thanks for the support!

```
package interfaces;

/**
 * Interface with all methods for the data-structs I have to learn for the exam
 *
 * <C> is the class of the Elements to be entered ex: ListItem<T>
 * <T> the type of the elements stored in the data-structs
 * 
 * @author 
 */
public interface ExamPreparation<C, T> {

    boolean insert(C item, int pos);

    boolean insert(T key, int pos);

    boolean insertAtHead(C item);

    boolean insertAtHead(T key);

    boolean insertAtTail(C item);

    boolean insertAtTail(T key);

    boolean insertSorted(C item, Comparator<T> comp);

    boolean insertSorted(T key, Comparator<T> comp);


    // ========== Remove Methods ==========

    boolean remove(T key);

    boolean removeAll(T key);


    // ========== Overwrite Methods ==========

    /**
     * takes the first appearance of oldKey and overwrites it wit
    h newKey
     *
     * @param newKey
     * @param oldKey
     * @return true if overwrited. False if oldKey is not in list
     */
    boolean overwrite(T newKey, T oldKey);

    /**
     * takes all the oldKeys and overwrites it with the newKey
     *
     * @param newKey
     * @param oldKey
     * @return returns true if at least one oldkey was found
     */
    boolean overwriteAll(T newKey, T oldKey);

    /**
     * overwrite at position
     *
     * @param newKey
     * @param pos
     * @return returns false if pos is not valid else true
     */
    boolean overwriteAt(T newKey, int pos);


    // ========== Other ==========

    boolean contains(T key); 
}
```

Comment: drop the `C` and just use `T` as you explained already `insert(T)` and `insert(ListElement<T>)` is perfectly fine and does not conflict.

Comment: Have a look at the [Java Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) (or better - the sources): The structural objects,  with which each collection _internally_ manages itself, is not known outside the collection class!

Comment: Why would I, as the user, want to know about heads of other lists? Look at Java's implementation of the Collection API - a `LinkedList` is just a `List`. Don't expose internal implementation details in the public API.

Comment: `ExamPreparation<String, String>` - now you have clashing methods. The rawtype is even worse.

Comment: Explaining the error: Generics are subject to _type erasure_. In fact, both methods simply compile as `insert(Object)`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I see your point. Thats way you could simply use insert(key) but with insert(ListItem<T>) you can add more than one element at once. I can think of situations that could be useful.

Comment: Just name the method that inserts all the elements of a list differently, like `insertAll(ListItem<T>)`. This is what standard collections do.

Comment: Java Collections have `addAll(Collection` which take another collection and add all the items. Your list can figure out that the user wants to add another list and ask for the head internally. Again _hide implementation details_.

Comment: okay many thanks for the good answers! As described I now use a insertAll method. Seams to be the best solution.

Comment: As others have pointed out: You should think about whether there should be the option to insert "items" and "keys" **at all**. Buf **if** you want both options: Why not name the methods accordingly? `insertItem` and `insertKey` or so. Be specific. See the headaches caused by the `List` interface, with `remove(T t)` and `remove(int index)`. For the case of `List<Integer>`, this causes **very** subtle bugs. Naming the methods `removeElement` or `removeByIndex` could have avoided many issues here...

Answer (score 1):

How about declaring a new interface

```
interface ElementType<T> {

}
```

and then making the possible element types; extend or implement `ElememtType` like this:

```
interface ListItem<T> extends ElementType<T> {

}

interface TreeNode<T> extends ElementType<T> {

}
```

and finally changing the declaration of  `ExamPreparation`
 from

```
public interface ExamPreparation<C,  T>
```

to

```
public interface ExamPreparation<C extends ElementType<T>,  T>
```

So that the following code compiles with no problem;

```
    ListItem<String> item = null;
    ExamPreparation<ListItem<String>, String> examPreparation = null;
    boolean isInserted;
    isInserted = examPreparation.insert("12", 0);
    isInserted = examPreparation.insert(item, 0);
```

Comment: `C extends Collection<T>`? Why would that help given what the OP has described?

Comment: just declaring `C` without any relation to `T` will make this interface violate what the can and cannot be called as element. like `T` is element of what? so this kind of declaration makes it clear

Comment: @BoristheSpider you are right, I was wrong. How about the edited post?